# Modify usual hpfilter function to ignore na's

Tags: r, xts

I'm a new R user, trying to learn quickly, but I couldn't crack this myself. I work mostly with economic time series – hence, try to maintain my dataset in xts multi-column format, e.g.:

```
> head(USDATAq)
         tq   ngdp    rgdp  profit
1947 Q1   0  237.2  1770.7    20.7
1947 Q2   1  240.4  1768.0    23.9
1947 Q3   2  244.5  1766.5    23.8
1947 Q4   3  254.3  1793.3    25.5
1948 Q1   4  260.3  1821.8    29.4
1948 Q2   5  267.3  1855.3    31.2
```

I apply the `hpfilter` function for filtering. [Elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5674714/i-lose-my-time-index-in-r-all-the-time-what-can-i-do-about-it) on this site, I found this implementation which uses the `coredata` function to apply `hpfilter` to xts objects:

```
hpfilter <- function(x, lambda=2){
  eye <- diag(length(x))
  dcrossprod <- crossprod(diff(eye, lag=1, d=2))
  coredata(x) <- solve(eye + lambda * dcrossprod, coredata(x))
  return(x)
}
```

My question is:

How can I modify the function so that it will work with variables having NA observations (at present, it calculates NA for the entire date range if there is any NA)?

I can pass on the dataset as `na.omit(USDATAq)`, which works, but this curtails all variables in dataset to the minimum observations. But, different variables are available until different dates, followed by NA's. I would like to eventually apply the function to every column of the dataset in a loop or `mapply`, so that the function returns each filtered series using all available observations of that series.

Comment: At a quick glance (not being familiar with this area, but being capable of reading R code) it seems as though this is as much a statistical, or definitional problem, as an R coding problem.  How would you want the method, which depends on lagged variables, to work?  Should it just drop all rows within one unit of a missing value [this guess is based on a quick skim of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodrick%E2%80%93Prescott_filter ] ? Is that reasonable, or will it get you in trouble for some forms of missingness ... ??

Comment: Guess you where referring to my earlier discussion about modifying Farnsworth' initial hpfilter to keep ts / zoo information, I just linked it now.

Comment: Yes ran2, I picked up your modification to include coredata in the definition. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Thanks Ben. Yes, you're right – the hpfilter uses the history; hence, missing observations are logically tricky. But here, I'm referring only to missing data at the beginning and end (that is the range for which data are available at this time, that's all). Missing obs in the middle would be an entirely different matter. Typically this is not a problem with mainstream macroeconomic data, though. So, I want the function to return filtered data for the dates that the raw data range allows for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. Why not just add na.omit inside this function? Just before creating the `eye` matrix? `x<-na.omit(x)`. Then you all you have to do is pass univariate series to it instead of whole data.frames. In other words: Leave the function as it is, add na.omit and combine it with `lapply` (or whatever form of the `apply` family (sapply,tapply,lapply) suits you best.

Comment: The only tricky part might be re-padding with NAs to make the columns match up properly afterward ... i.e. something like `filtered.x <- x; filtered.x[!is.na(x)] <- hpfilter(x[!is.na(x)],...)`

Comment: True. Still it depends on what you want to do. Sometimes i'd prefer a `list` of univariate series over one `data.frame`. Particularly when it comes to plotting. Yet in Dynamic Linear Models, e.g. with `dynlm` the latter is more convenient. However, good to see the OP figured it out.

Comment: @hans0l0 What if we replace the NA's by 0? If needed, easy to replace 0 with NA back again. Time series are sometimes padded with 0 for avoiding endpoint problem anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @ran2. I worked on your suggestion and managed to solve the problem – but, in a rather inelegant way. First of all, I could not get any of the 'apply family' functions to work correctly on an xts object, maintaining its structure. Plain apply with the apply(x, MARGIN=2,..) for column-wise application showed promise, but stalled at the 'coredata' statement. lapply etc yielded mangled lists.

I then went to the for loop. But because the x<-na.omit(x) changes the length of the variable, it cannot replace the original within loop.

```
> for(i in 1:ncol(USDATAq)) {
+ USDATAq[,i]<-hpfilter(USDATAq[,i])
+ }
```

> Error in NextMethod(.Generic) : 
>         number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

So, I had to add unseemly code to hpfilter to ‘merge’ the result back to the original (with NA) and then return the variable. This merging matches the 2 variables by date (hence, length) filling NA’s into the result. Then, this result can replace the original in a loop. In conclusion, I had to modify hpfilter to:

```
hpfilter <- function(x,lambda=2){
y<-na.omit(x)
eye <- diag(length(y))
coredata(y) <- solve(eye + lambda * crossprod(diff(eye, lag=1, d=2)), coredata(y))
xy<-merge(x,y) 
return(xy[,2])
}
```

and then use the loop above, to finally get error free results. My knowledge of R is so rudimentary, though, that there probably are easier ways to do this. But, at least, I can proceed now. Thanks to all for pointing me in the right direction. I'd still welcome further corrections to my code above.

Comment: +1 for good spirit and leveraging hints to solve your own problem.

Comment: Thanks Ben. All's well that ends well....for the time being. Thanks also for your tip above on the re-aligning. I got stuck exactly on that....at some stage, core R would benefit from providing a special 'calendar' workspace for time series, where synching variables to calendar dates would be automatic (once defined)....

Answer (score 0):

With zoo objects, it is marginally cleaner using `attributes()` rather than `coredata()` then you can merge straight back into the zoo object. (I haven't tried this for xts objects):

```
hpfilter <- function(x,lambda=1600){
    y<-na.omit(x)
    eye <- diag(length(y))
    result <- solve(eye+lambda*crossprod(diff(eye,lag=1,d=2)),y)
    attributes(result) <- attributes(y)
    return(result)
}
```